# Create drop down list from List ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razorengine, dropdownlistfor

I have strongly typed view model and in one of class object I am passing list of options that I need to present in @html.Dropdownlist

### View Model

```
 public class CreateCampaign_VM
{
    public MarketingCampaign MarketingCampaign { get; set; }

    public List<MarketingCampaignType> MarketingCampaignType { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller method

```
 private CreateCampaign_VM GetCampaignObject()
    {
        CreateCampaign_VM _CampaignObject = new CreateCampaign_VM();


        _CampaignObject.MarketingCampaignType.Add(new MarketingCampaignType {
            CampaignTypeID = 1,
            CampaignTypeTitle = "Email",
            Description = "Email"
        });

        _CampaignObject.MarketingCampaignType.Add(new MarketingCampaignType
        {
            CampaignTypeID = 2,
            CampaignTypeTitle = "Text",
            Description = "Text"
        });

        _CampaignObject.MarketingCampaignType.Add(new MarketingCampaignType
        {
            CampaignTypeID = 3,
            CampaignTypeTitle = "Post",
            Description = "Post"
        });

        return _CampaignObject;
    }
```

...

```
 public ActionResult CreateCampaign_Title()
    {
        return PartialView("CreateCampaign_Title_Partial", GetCampaignObject());
    }
```

### Razor view

```
@model App.Business.Entities.CreateCampaign_VM
  @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateCampaign_Title", "Campaign", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "CreateCampaignTitleForm" }))
        {
         .....
          @Html.DropDownListFor(// 'MarketingCampaignType object' need help here 
         //...
       }
```

Comment: What property of `MarketingCampaign` are you wanting to bind to? And since you using a view model, you should not be including a proeprty which is a data model, and the collection property should be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, not `List<MarketingCampaignType>`

Comment: _CampaignObject  that is instance CreateCampaign_VM.MarketingCampaignType

Comment: Hi @toxic you will also need a property to store selectedValue for your dropDownList

Comment: That was not my question :). You need to bind to a property - which property do you want to bind to

Comment: is CampaignTypeTitle I want to show in drop down list and with ids of CampaignTypeID

Comment: You still have not said what property you want to bind to - but it need to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MarketingCampaign.SomeProperty, new SelectList(Model.MarketingCampaignType, "CampaignTypeID", "CampaignTypeTitle "))` but as I noted above, your view model should be designed so that its `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCampaign, Model.CampaignList)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MarketingCampaign , new SelectList(Model.MarketingCampaignType, "CampaignTypeTitle", "CampaignTypeId"), new { id = "yourElementIdIfAny", @class = "yourClassNameIfAny" })
```